# how add click event and get the dom in the iframe with react-frame-component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-component

i use the react-frame-component create a iframe,i want to bind a click event on the iframe and get the dom that id is abc in the iframe. how do that?

above is my code,it's will output null, get the element is not working.what wrong with my code.Help will be appreciated.Thanks.

```
...
componentDidMount() {

    var iframe = document.getElementById("ccc");
    console.log(iframe);

    var iwindow = iframe.contentWindow;

    console.log(iwindow);

    var idoc = iwindow.document;

    console.log(idoc);

    console.log(idoc.getElementById('abc'));


  }
return (
      <div>
        <Frame id="ccc">
          <div id="abc">
            <div>this.state.show is true and now I'm visible</div>
          </div>
        </Frame>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Just curious, what is the purpose of this?

Comment: @entiendoNull  Recently，i am working a html to sketch plugin.i am use the html-sketchapp(https://github.com/html-sketchapp/html-sketchapp) to generater sketch file from some react component.in sketch plugin panel,i use the iframe include the component so that need get the component's dom to generater sketch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [contentDidMount](https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component#contentdidmount-and-contentdidupdate) prop (not componentDidMount).

> contentDidMount and contentDidUpdate are conceptually equivalent to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, respectively. The reason these are needed is because internally we call ReactDOM.render which starts a new set of lifecycle calls. This set of lifecycle calls are sometimes triggered after the lifecycle of the parent component, so these callbacks provide a hook to know when the frame contents are mounted and updated.

**This code should print console.log properly**

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {}

  contentMounted() {
    console.log("---------1");
    var iframe = document.getElementById("ccc");
    console.log("1", iframe);

    var iwindow = iframe.contentWindow;

    console.log("2", iwindow);

    var idoc = iwindow.document;

    console.log("3", idoc);

    console.log("4", idoc.getElementById("abc"));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Frame id="ccc" contentDidMount={this.contentMounted}>
          <div id="abc">
            <div>this.state.show is true and now I'm visible</div>
          </div>
        </Frame>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work...

```
import { FrameContextConsumer } from 'react-frame-component';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const frameWindow = useRef(null);

    const getInnerHTML = () => {
        const iframeWindow = frameWindow.current;
        if(!iframeWindow) return;

        // here you got the iframe window object
        // work with it as you like
    };

    return (
        <Iframe onClick={getInnerHTML}>
            <FrameContextConsumer>
                {(frameContext) => {
                    const { document, window } = frameContext;
                    frameWindow.current = window;

                    return <div>Your content goes in this return statement</div>
                }}
            </FrameContextConsumer>
        </Iframe>
    )
};
```